# Add value to a column each month in Mysql DataBase using Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Hello I wanted to ask is there a way to update a column in a table in Mysql DB with a value that I can give from a form and so it updates the column every month with that value

The situation is that I want to update the column balance in the table leaves adding a certain amount of days each month to each employee.

I was thinking to use Cron Jobs but I'm not sure how to call them specifically for each user on a form

Comment: **I can give from a form and so it updates the column every month with that value** you want the same value should be updated every month?

Comment: More like the value gets added like for example current value + the new value

Comment: can you give a example which sort of value you will update, **each user on a form** ? what do you mean by *form** does individual user has to interact while updating ?

Comment: Value passing by form is one time or you pass every month?

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani I want to show all users in a table then add values on a column thats on the users table

Comment: @IrshadKhan that value should be passed every month for the selected user yes

Comment: value is constant or dynamic mean same value upated or different value?

Comment: @IrshadKhan well the value present + the new value so it starts from 0 then it adds for example 2 and then every month it should do 2 + 2 = 4 then 4 + 2 = 6 and such